# retrun sources in Bokeh javascript callback

Tags: python, bokeh

Imagine [this](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.3.2/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-model-property-events) example in Bokeh docs:

```py
# modified to by used in a notebook

from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_notebook, show

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var f = cb_obj.value
    var x = data['x']
    var y = data['y']
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = column(slider, plot)

show(layout)
```

I was wondering if there's a way to use the (most recent) value of `y` after changing the widget to be used in other computations in the next cells of a notebook. What occurred to my mind was returning `y` in the callback but I'm open to any other idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full synchronization between the Python runtime and the JS output, you would have to embed a Bokeh server application in the notebook. (The Bokeh server is *specifically the thing whose job is to keeps things in sync.*) Otherwise all output in a Jupyter noteboook is uni-directional only, Python -> JavaScript, with no updates coming back to the Python kernel.

You can see an example notebook with a Bokeh server app embedded here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb